# Show that $i^m + i^{m+1} + i^{m+2} + i^{m+3} = 0$ for all $m ∈ \mathbb N$

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-verification

Here is the long answer I have come up with so far.

m is a natural number

If m is divided by 4 :-

Let n be the quotient and r be the remainder

Then m = 4n+r where 0<=r<4

> i<sup>m</sup> = i<sup>(4n + r)</sup>
>
> = i<sup>4n</sup> * i<sup>r</sup>
>
> = (i<sup>4</sup>)<sup>n</sup> * i<sup>r</sup>
>
> = (i<sup>2</sup> * i<sup>2</sup>)<sup>n</sup> * i<sup>r</sup>
>
> = (-1*-1)<sup>n</sup> * i<sup>r</sup>
>
> = 1<sup>n</sup> * i<sup>r</sup>
>
> = 1 * i<sup>r</sup>
>
> = i<sup>r</sup>

∴ m = r

For all natural numbers; r = 0, 1, 2 or 3

∴ m = 0, 1, 2 or 3 (as m=r)        ***[1]***

Let r = 0

Then m = 0 (as r=m and r=0)

> i<sup>m</sup> + i<sup>m+1</sup> + i<sup>m+2</sup> + i<sup>m+3</sup>
>
> = i<sup>0</sup> + i<sup>1</sup> + i<sup>2</sup> + i<sup>3</sup>
> = 1 + i - 1 + i<sup>2</sup>*i 
>
> = 1 + i - 1 - i 
>
> = 0 **[2]***

Let r = 1

Then m = 1 (as r=m and r=1)

> i<sup>m</sup> + i<sup>m+1</sup> + i<sup>m+2</sup> + i<sup>m+3</sup>
>
> = i<sup>1</sup> + i<sup>2</sup> + i<sup>3</sup> + i<sup>4</sup>
> = i - 1 + i*i<sup>2</sup> + i<sup>2</sup>*i<sup>2</sup> 
>
> = i - 1 - i + -1*-1 
>
> = i - 1 - 1 + 1 = 0 **[3]***

Let r = 2

Then m = 2 (as r=m and r=2)

> i<sup>m</sup> + i<sup>m+1</sup> + i<sup>m+2</sup> + i<sup>m+3</sup>
>
> = i<sup>2</sup> + i<sup>3</sup> + i<sup>4</sup> + i<sup>5</sup>
> = -1 - i + 1 + i<sup>2</sup>*i<sup>3</sup> 
> = -1 - i + 1 - 1 * -i 
> = -1 - i + 1 + i 
> = 0 ***[4]***

Let r = 3

Then m = 3 (as r=m and r=3)

> i<sup>m</sup> + i<sup>m+1</sup> + i<sup>m+2</sup> + i<sup>m+3</sup>
>
> = i<sup>3</sup> + i<sup>4</sup> + i<sup>5</sup> + i<sup>6</sup>
> = -i + 1 + i + i<sup>2</sup>*i<sup>4</sup> 
> = -i + 1 + i - 1 * 1 
> = -i + 1 + i - 1 
> = 0 ***[5]***

From ***[1]***, ***[2]***, ***[3]***, ***[4]*** and ***[5]***

i<sup>m</sup> + i<sup>m+1</sup> + i<sup>m+2</sup> + i<sup>m+3</sup> = 0 for all m ∈ Natural numbers

Could someone please help me improve/shorten this answer?

Comment: "Could someone please help me improve/shorten this answer?" Sure. Factor out $i^m$.

Comment: `<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>` is very rarely useful, if at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following holds for every integer $m$, nonnegative or not:

- $i^m + i^{m+1} + i^{m+2} + i^{m+3} =i^m \times ( i^0 + i^1+i^2+i^3)$
- $i^0+i^1+i^2+i^3=1+i-1-i=0$

Comment: This is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

$$ 0 =i^4\!-1 = (\color{#c00}{i\!-\!1})(i^3\!+\!i^2\!+\!i\!+\!1)\,\color{#c00}{\overset{\rm cancel}{\Longrightarrow}}\,i^3\!+\!i^2\!+\!i\!+\!1=0\,\overset{\large \times\, i^n}\Longrightarrow i^{n+3}\!+\!i^{n+2}\!+\!i^{n+1}\!+\!i^n = 0$$

**Remark** $ $ The proof works in *any* ring for *any* root of $\:i\,$ of $\,x^4\!-1\,$ such that $\,\color{#c00}{i\!-\!1}\,$ is $\color{#c00}{\rm cancelable}$, e.g. for $\ i = 2 \in \Bbb Z/15,\ $ i.e. $\ i\equiv 2\pmod{\!15}.\,$ The other proofs don't work this generally because they use $\,i^2 \equiv -1\,$ (vs.  $\,i^2\equiv 4 \not\equiv -1\pmod{\!15}\,$ in prior example).

Comment: @Downvoter If something is not clear then please feel welcome to ask for elaboration in comments. Note that you can ignore the remark and simply view the proof in $\,\Bbb C\, $ vs. more general rings. The point of the remark is to emphasize that one can present a more *universal* proof wtih no extra effort (and no extra complexity).

Comment: There seems to be a wild, trolling downvoter lately in the site. The question is tagged "complex numbers" so I think the asker meant ny $\;i\;$ the imaginary unit here, and if he's having problems with this question then he may not understand your answer, which I find very interesting. +1

Answer (score 1):

One hint for a short answer would be that $i^{n+2}=i^2(i^n)=-i^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:-**

Note that $m\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4$ and $i^4=1$.